# Swift: can't add SKProductsRequestDelegate protocol to GameScene class?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase

So I'm trying to implement in app purchases in my sprite kit game and I'm working in Swift. I know I need to add the `SKProductsRequestDelegate` and `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` protocols to my `GameScene` class in order to do this, but when I add them I get the error:

```
Type 'GameScene' does not conform to protocol 'SKProductsRequestDelegate'
```

and a similar error for `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`.

I imported `StoreKit` and here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import StoreKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not enough to claim conformance, you actually have to implement the required methods of the protocol. And I think SKProductsRequestDelegate has a subprotocol. But all in all, are you sure that GameScene is the class that should handle store transactions? I'd prefer a separate class handling store transactions and nothing else.

Comment: Where can I find the methods for the protocols?

Comment: See methods marked as _Required_ [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequestDelegate/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKProductsRequestDelegate/productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/)

Answer (score 6):

You probably have the old version of the function paymentQueue like this:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject])    {... }
```

This functions now is declared like this:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])    {... }
```

The productRequest should be declare like this:

```
func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {... }
```

This is because you have to implement this methods to conform the protocol

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Swift (yet) but it seems that what Swift calls protocol is what the rest of us call **Interface**.
If I am right, then u need to implement, yourself, all the methods that the protocol u "signed" on (i.e. **promised** the compiler your class will implement).
So, if a protocol has a method `func doSomething()->String` **You need** to actually **write** this method in your class yourself in order for your class to conform to the protocol.